What's the numeral name of the recently launched Starlink satellites and where can I track them?
I'd like to track the recently launched Starlink sats that reached a too low orbit due to the Falcon 9 second stage leak and MVac Engine RUD. For some reason, if I wanna enter "Launch 11 July 2024" (or 12 July, depending on time zone) in this Starlink tracker, the option doesn't show up.
The Starlink Group is called 9-3, but they must have a longer numeral name as those suggested on the tracker, right? What is it and/or where can I track the recently launched Starlinks?

I stumbled upon one of the number 11221 by poking around randomly on a tracking site. Searching on that number led me to a page on Jonathan McDowell's site with a list of satellite numbers for the launch, although it seems to be a page that he started to build for this launch but didn't complete. Keeping in mind that these satellites were placed into an elliptical orbit with a perigee of 135 km which is high drag, they are essentially fighting for their lives as they keep dipping into the upper atmosphere, and are not expected to survive long, so tracking is much more difficult as the orbits keep changing.
Here is the list that was on the page that I found:
Starlink Group 9-3 (Launch 181, 2024-129)
Starlink 11214
Starlink 11202
Starlink 11212
Starlink 11219
Starlink 11216
Starlink 11220
Starlink 11218
Starlink 11195
Starlink 11211
Starlink 11215
Starlink 11217
Starlink 11222
Starlink 11221
Starlink 32157
Starlink 32146
Starlink 31832
Starlink 31839
Starlink 31743
Starlink 31847
Starlink 31831
Entering these numbers into various trackers doesn't seem to work which again is understandable.
I am not posting the link since I don't think this is an officially published page and it may eventually be deleted.

Here is the link to the page. I can delete this comment if the page goes away.

If you create an account on Space-Track, you can get access to information published by the 18th Space Defense Squadron. The information sometimes takes a little while to come out, but you can build an API query with their Query Builder tool with predicates like:



Predicate
Operator
Value




LAUNCH_DATE
=
2024-07-11


OBJECT_NAME
Like
STARLINK



Which would give you information on all Starlinks launched on July 11, 2024 (the launch date involving the falcon 9 upper stage failure).
This would not give you any information at time of writing (2024-07-16) since we're still fairly close to that launch, but will do what you're asking in the future.
